# Why does a string index return an integer value instead of a character?

Tags: ruby, bash, executable

It appears that when putting Ruby code in an executable script, the index of a String behaves differently than it does in IRB or by running the Ruby code directly.  For example:

```
$ cat > test
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
puts 'hello'[0]
$ chmod +x test
$ ./test
104
$ ruby -e "puts 'hello'[0]"
h
```

Why is this? And, how do I make the executable script behave the same as "normal" Ruby code?

Comment: Running different ruby version ?

Comment: Sounds like those two answers worked for you.  You should accept one of them so that future visitors to this page know which one worked best. (And to make the answerers happy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prior to 1.9, Ruby returned the ASCII character code for single characters. 1.9+ switched to returning the character itself:

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
irb(main):002:0> 'foo'[0]
=> 102
```

```
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"
irb(main):002:0> 'foo'[0]
=> "f"
```

Using the constant `RUBY_VERSION` is a good way to debug this sort of problem quickly.

Answer (score 2):

when typing `ruby`, are you sur you are using `/usr/bin/ruby` ? You might have a different version of ruby in your $PATH taking precedence over this one.

I'm not quite sure about this, but I wouldn't be surprised if `String#[]` has a different return wether you're using ruby 1.8, or 1.9

Comment: Yep, I just checked and my system Ruby is 1.8.7. When using #!/usr/bin/env ruby (I use rvm and have it set to 1.9.3 currently) in my executable, the result is as expected. Thank you so much!!!